# sqlite3 -Infinity value in Float field

Tags: oracle, sqlite

I am converting Oracle tables into a sqlite3 Database and stuck at the "-Infinity"-value in a float field.

The snippet of the Oracle "Create Table" statement is

```
"X1" FLOAT(126)
```

How do I convert the "-Infinity" value correctly into a sqlite3 table?

Comment: How exactly are you doing the conversion? What is the problem with the current conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I chose "REAL" as data type and just stored "-Infinity" inside it. Seems to work.

Comment: hello friend. how would you explain select case when 0 = cast ('-infinity' as real) then 'bad' else 'good' end; ?

Answer (score 0):

the infinity seems to be 1e10000,
as defined by standard and explained  [here](https://%22Handling%20of%20IEEE-754%20nan%20and%20+/-inf%20in%20SQLite?%22%20https://sqlite-users.sqlite.narkive.com/JgSgkiek/handling-of-ieee-754-nan-and-inf-in-sqlite)